# Python tkinter and grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have some problems with tkinter and grid. Help writes that i can use `in=master` option, but when I try, I get a message `invalid syntax`. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.title("Gallery")
text=Text(root)
text.grid(in=master)
root.mainloop()
```

Can anyone explain to me what the problem is?

Comment: `in` is a reserved keyword in Python, so this cannot work... where did you read that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you mean by "help"? Are you referring to the output of `help(root)` or maybe `help(text.grid)`?

Comment: @BryanOakley I meant `help(Text(Tk()).grid)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method), it states you need to use `in_`, as `in` is a reserved word in python--that's why you are getting your syntax error because `in` isn't being treated as a keyword.

> Note that **in** is a reserved word in Python. To use it as a keyword option, append an underscore (**in_**).

Also, you don't have `master` defined anywhere in your code. Perhaps you meant `root`?